# Google Sheets - Creating a button to run on a column selected by the user

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to have a user click/highlight a column (or a checkbox at the top of the column, then click a single button to run the script on all checked columns.

```
     var values1 = "Pass";
  // Where to look for Auto:
  var enabledDisabled = sheet.getRange("B3:B140").getValues();
  var testResultsRange = sheet.getRange("AL3:AL140");
  var testResults = testResultsRange.getValues();
  // Keyword to look for in Auto: column
  var putValues = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < enabledDisabled.length; i++) {
    if (enabledDisabled[i][0] === "Yes") {
      putValues.push([values1]);
    } else {
      putValues.push([testResults[i][0]]); // Push the existing cell value
    }
  }
  //  Put value1 inside row, column# for test result
  testResultsRange.setValues(putValues);
```

Instead of hardcoded ranges, I'd like it to run on every column that is checked, basically.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One solution I usually use is to put checkboxes on the first row of the columns, then with onEdit I run the script by clicking on the checkbox and by detecting the column by getColumn ()

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var cel = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (sh.getName()=='mySheet' and cel.getValue()){
    var col = cel.getColumn()
    // run your script in column 'col'
    cel.setValue(!cel.getValue())
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that looks a lot like what I'm trying to achieve.
I'm still pretty new at this - How do I use that exactly? 

Would be awesome to be able to  add a checkbox to each column needed, then hit a button and run the script all each column.

To add a bit more detail:
I'd like to have that script check a different (constant) column, on the same row, for a specific text value (ex: "Yes"), then perform the action if that text is present.

The problem I'm running into is having that occur on each row of the column

Comment: I encourage you to set up a sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Edited my initial post - hopefully it's a bit more clear what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Can you please provide a sample sheet with this code and a few data. Which column will be adapted B or AL in your script ?

Comment: Hi, 
Basically, I want to actually replace the specific columns with a dynamic range (each vertical column would have a checkbox, the script would then run on each column where the checkbox was "TRUE".
There are dozens of columns.

Comment: Hi, sorry, misunderstood the question at the time. 
I'm looking to replace the range AL with a simple checkbox. 
So if I run the script, it processes columns with checkboxes at the top